# Angular 6 getting the value of an array at Index[i][j] interpolation issue

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, interpolation, angular6

I am dynamically creating components in a an Angular 6 app, and need to access the contents of a text field. The text field is contained in dynamically created array. Parent array[i] contains child components[j] and I need to find the value of the child component.

Html for component as follows:

```
<input class="fileInput" id="file{{i}}_{{j}}" #file{{i}}_{{j}} (change)="save(i, j, (file+i+_+j).value)" />
```

Function call to save:

```
 save(index1: number, index2: number, val) {
    console.log('index1: ' + index1 + ' index2: ' + index2 + ' value: ' + val);

  }
```

currently my console logs the value **val** as undefined and I am sure it is because

Comment: have you ever heard of two-way binding? Because you are inventing `ngModel` right now

Comment: You forgot to use quotes? `(change)="save(i, j, ('file' + i + '_' + j).value)"`

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal the whole concept `(file+i+_+j).value)` is absurd, even if you use quotes here, you get string and try to access property `value` of string, which is `undefined`.

Comment: @smnbbrv Ah, thanks, didn't know. Will delete answer.

Comment: @smnbbrv I will freely admit that my angular is old and rusty, my syntax is probably wrong, and am attempting to access the child array incorrectly. I wanted to at least try (prefferably incorrectly than not at all) before I posted the question. I would like to use 2 way binding, thus my attempt at interpolation, but I am doing it wrong and looking for the correct way to do this.

Comment: the way to do your thing right is `<input class="fileInput" #file (change)="save(i, j, file.value)" />`. That's pretty much it. Every of your change events will have its own `file` reference. No interpolation, because it is not required here. Or, probably, specifically to your case `<input class="fileInput" (change)="save(i, j, $event.target.value)" />` without even using element reference

Comment: THANK YOU @smnbbrv `<input class="fileInput" #file (change)="save(i, j, file.value)" />`. did it. I was over-complicating this whole thing and you were correct, as I'm sure you already knew, lol.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the question comments by @smnbbrv, I was using the ngmodel 2 way binding incorrectly. A simple change to my code (removing my poor attempt at interpolation), fixed the issues.

correct code in the **html** portion should have been:

```
    <input class="fileInput" #file (change)="save(i, j, file.value)" />
```